# iOS dev on xcode 3.2

Tags: xcode3.2

I've been doing a lot of work on trying to create a hello world app for iOS, and I found a tutorial that had me create a iOS type project, but whenever I get to the template selection screen, I am only given Mac OSX, but in the video, the person had a category called "iOS"

NOTE:  they were using 4.2

I was wondering, what project type would let me do iOS, or could I download some sort of template?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need the iOS SDK which you can obtain from the [Apple Developer page](https://developer.apple.com/downloads/index.action?q=xcode). But I am not sure if versions that are compiled with such an old version of the SDK will work on the new Iphones that come with iOS 5/6.